# Command to fetch the complete word in quotes

Tags: sed, echo, cut

We have a value

```
XX_EMAIL_GL_BTCH_ATTACH FCP_REQID=8830260 FCP_LOGIN="APPS/pwd" FCP_USERID=4807 FCP_USERNAME="USER" FCP_PRINTER="noprint" FCP_SAVE_OUT=Y FCP_NUM_COPIES=1 "XX WBP 8-501 Misc Receipts" "xyz.mno@abc.com"
```

We need to fetch the value `XX WBP 8-501 Misc Receipts`.

We tried as below, but it is returning only XX.

```
echo XX_EMAIL_GL_BTCH_ATTACH FCP_REQID=8830260 FCP_LOGIN="APPS/pwd" FCP_USERID=4807 FCP_USERNAME="USER" FCP_PRINTER="noprint" FCP_SAVE_OUT=Y FCP_NUM_COPIES=1 "XX WBP 8-501 Misc Receipts" "xyz.mno@abc.com" | cut -d" " -f9 | sed 's/"//g'
```

Comment: Is the value in a file, or a shell variable, or ???

Comment: `cut -d \" -f 8 < sample` would do it on your sample.

Answer (score 2):

Following your pattern you just need to add some columns to `cut`:

```
cut -d' ' -f9-13 | sed 's/"//g'
```

You could also use a pure `sed` solution:

```
sed 's/.*"\(.*\)" ".*"$/\1/'
```

The pattern depends on two double-quoted strings at the end. With that it displays the first of the two (or IOW the second to last double-quoted sub-string from the full string).

**Update:** With `echo` as OP seems to want...

```
echo 'XX_EMAIL_GL_BTCH_ATTACH FCP_REQID=8830260 FCP_LOGIN="APPS/pwd" FCP_USERID=4807 FCP_USERNAME="USER" FCP_PRINTER="noprint" FCP_SAVE_OUT=Y FCP_NUM_COPIES=1 "XX WBP 8-501 Misc Receipts" "xyz.mno@abc.com"' | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)" ".*"$/\1/'
```

Comment: Hi,f9-13 will not always work.... the value may vary. So, what I need is to fetch the value which is in that double quotes

Comment: You need to add all relevant details like this to your question. Anyways, the sed-only solution should work.

Comment: Hi, could you please let me know how to achieve this..... As I said before, sed is fetching only XX, but I need complete XX WBP 8-501 Misc Receipts

Comment: I took the full string from your question and put it in a file and then did `sed '...' file` and I get `XX WBP 8-501 Misc Receipts`. Are you sure you're typing it in correctly?

Comment: If you don't want to put it in a file you have to surround the string with (single) quotes as I show in the update to my answer.

Comment: As I said before, that 'XX WBP 8-501 Misc Receipts', this is not constant. This complete word may vary. some times it may be single word, or it may be 2 words or 4 or 5...... It is something like, that value is coming from some other place.

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as it's surrounded by double quotes and followed by another double quoted string. As I said in my answer. If you can't even guarantee that then you're not going to get a solution...there has to be a pattern.

Comment: So, what I simply needs is any value which is in f9 place and in double quotes, I need

Comment: `cut` is not going to work if the number of columns you want to cut varies.

Comment: plce is fixed, it is always f9

Comment: No that's not how it works. `cut` relies on a single delimeter. I suggest you give up on `cut` and use one of the alternatives offered here. I'm out.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get a robust solution using `cut` while extracting *logical* substrings from such kind of input.

Use one of the following solid solutions:

1) **`Python`** command (simplified):

```
python -c 'import csv,sys; r=csv.reader(sys.stdin, delimiter=" "); print(next(r)[8])' <file
```

*Python*'s [**csv**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv) module id pretty good to read and write tabular data.

---

2) GNU **`awk`** command:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^"]+' '{ gsub("\"","",$8); print $8 }' file
```

---

The output for **both** approaches:

```
XX WBP 8-501 Misc Receipts
```

---

Comment: Considering the resistance to using only `sed` this is a long shot. ;) Seems OP really wants a solution with `cut` despite the fact that it won't work since the length of the string to cut can vary.

Comment: @BLayer, the input string is NOT suitable to split by whitespaces, it has an evident csv structure - i.e. words with spaces enclosed with quotes `.. FCP_NUM_COPIES=1 "XX WBP 8-501 Misc Receipts" "xyz.mno@abc.com"`

Comment: Preaching to the choir. Read my comments below my answer.

Comment: @BLayer, yes, your approach is not for complex csv data

Comment: I think you're missing my point....which is simply that OP is intent on using `cut` rather than `sed` or `Python` or whatever.

Comment: @BLayer, he's doing wrong ...

Comment: _Thus my comment that you are "preaching to the choir". _  ... was my last comment and it was apparently removed. Why? I was just communicating to Roman that I agreed with him. Silly.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the way you `echo` the string, the shell will eat the double quotes, so you are not able to tell how far your ninth field goes. You you need to surround your string with single quotes first.

Then you have to consider that `cut` is just looking for spaces as delimiters and doesn't know how to ignore spaces inside of quotes, so do it this way:

```
echo 'XX_EMAIL_GL_BTCH_ATTACH FCP_REQID=8830260 FCP_LOGIN="APPS/pwd" FCP_USERID=4807 FCP_USERNAME="USER" FCP_PRINTER="noprint" FCP_SAVE_OUT=Y FCP_NUM_COPIES=1 "XX WBP 8-501 Misc Receipts" "xyz.mno@abc.com"' | cut -d" " -f9- | cut -d\" -f 2
```

The first `cut` keeps everything from the ninth field on, the second takes `"` as delimiter to keep just the part inside the first pair of quotes.

With pure `sed` the same could be done with

```
sed -E 's/([^ ]* ){8}//;s/"//;s/".*//'
```

In any case, you can break the script if you'll add spaces to earlier column fields.